# Unable to extend facebook access token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to extend my facebook access token, and following is what I did. However, i wasn't able to get the token extended, and when I check the facebook accesstoken debugger it still shows that the token is expiring in an hour.

any ideas?

```
    private string appId = "my app id";
    private string appSecret = "my app secret";
    private string returnUrl = "http://localhost:1868/callback";
    private string _scope = "user_about_me,publish_stream,user_videos,user_photos";

    [Test]
    public void GetFacebookLoginUrl()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.GetLoginUrl(
            new
                {
                    client_id = appId,
                    client_secret = appSecret,
                    redirect_uri = returnUrl,
                    response_type = "code",
                    scope = _scope
                }
            );
    }

    [Test]
    public void exchangeCodeForAccessToken()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = appId,
            client_secret = appSecret,
            redirect_uri = returnUrl,
            code = "got the code after user accepts the request"
        });
    }


    [Test]
    public void ExtendExpiryTimeOfAccessToken()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = appId,
            client_secret = appSecret,
            grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
            fb_exchange_token = "token from preview method"
        });
    }
```

**Solution**

after de-authorize the app from the users' accounts everything start making sense.
One thing to note tho, 
the code above actually gets a "long lived" access token back which is valid for 60 days and it can not be extended.

if a [Facebook client-side authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) is used, then one can extend it using the "ExtendExpiryTimeOfAccessToken" sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you initially started developing the application and signing in months ago before the offline access depreciation it is possible your affected by this bug.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/341793929223330

If you are affected you need to de-authorise the application and then try again, this doesn't affect new users.

Comment: yeah i think that was the cause, I have to de-authorise it then everything start to make sense.

Comment: Hopefully Facebook will fix the bug soon but given how long it has taken so far I am not holding my breath

Comment: @ArthurGuy do you mean each user would have to deauthorize/remove the app and add it again?

Comment: Thats the only way I have found to fix the issue. This might get resolved when offline access finally removed.